# Method cannot be translated into a store expression in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ, i am runing a query but i facing some issue please let me know what could be issue here is my query

```
    DBContex db = new DBContex ();
    var APIKey = db.Table.Where(a => a.APIKey == Guid.Parse(AppKey)).SingleOrDefault();
```

Error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Guid
>   Parse(System.String)'  method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

Comment: You're using Entity Framework, aren't you?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use (most of) C# in LinqToEF. `Guid.Parse` is not designed to work with EF.

The fix is to do this.

```
DBContex db = new DBContex ();
Guid appKey = Guid.Parse(appKeyString);
var APIKey = db.Table.Where(a => a.APIKey == appKey).SingleOrDefault();
```